# List files in directories using Glob() in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, path, glob

Basically, so far I have this code:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

# define ERROR 1
# define FAILURE -1

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  glob_t globlist;
  int i;

  i = 0;               
  if (ac == 1)
    return (-1);
  else
    {
      if (glob(av[1], GLOB_PERIOD, NULL, &globlist) == GLOB_NOSPACE
          || glob(av[1], GLOB_PERIOD, NULL, &globlist) == GLOB_NOMATCH)
        return (FAILURE);
      if (glob(av[1], GLOB_PERIOD, NULL, &globlist) == GLOB_ABORTED)
        return (ERROR);
      while (globlist.gl_pathv[i])
        {
          printf("%s\n", globlist.gl_pathv[i]);
          i++;
        }
    }
  return (0);
}
```

When I type `./a.out "*"` for example it prints all my files where I am, aswell as directories, but it doesn't print what is inside directories. How should I do to print ALL files, including sub-files/folders?

Thanks

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but you should not return `-1` from the `main` function. Return `0` on "success" and a *positive* value less than 256 on "failure". This is because on POSIX systems (which include Linux, OSX and all modern Unix systems) the higher bits have special meaning.

Comment: You might like to have a look at the functions prototyped in `dirent.h`.

Comment: @alk I know about dirent.h but I don't really know how to use it well. Like I think I have to do recursive, am I wrong?

Comment: yes, you have to do it recursive. So you'll want to put your `glob` code into a function (rather than in `main()`) . Also agree with advice about `return()`.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks! Basically I glob one first time, and then I access all directories, and I glob one more time?

Comment: you'll have to run the `glob()` on each directory entry that you find, even in the 2nd-to-N level subdirectories. Set up a small test dir with 3 levels of sub-dirs and 2-3 files in in each dir. If you try to run such code on your machine from the `/` dir, and debug it, you'll spend hours stepping thru all the nodes. Once your sample is working, go to a shallow branch in your "live" dir structure (maybe `/usr/local/share`) and then run your code there. FInally, spend some time looking at the source for the `find` utility program in unix/linux (Minix version, maybe). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thank you! Here is how I do it: I run the glob, and I try to opendir() each entry. If I can opendir it, it means that it's a directory, I go inside using readdir() and I call recursively my function. If I can't opendir(), I just print the entry. How does it sound to you?

Comment: Add an edit section near the top of your Q with your improved code. (Your change sounds reasonable, but without seeing your code, we can't say for sure). Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`nftw()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) instead of [`glob()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) if you want to examine entire trees, rather than one specific path and filename pattern.

(It is absolutely silly to reinvent the wheel by going at it using opendir()/readdir()/closedir(), especially because nftw() should handle filesystem changes gracefully, whereas self-spun tree walking code usually ignores all the hard stuff, and only works in optimal conditions on your own machine, failing in spectacular and wonderful ways elsewhere.)

In the filter function, use [`fnmatch()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) to decide whether the file name is acceptable using glob patterns.

If you wish to filter using regular expressions instead, use [`regcomp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html) to compile the pattern(s) before calling nftw(), then [`regexec()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regexec.3.html) in your filter function. (Regular expressions are more powerful than glob patterns, and they are compiled to a tight state machine, so they are quite efficient, too.)

If you are unsure about the difference, the Wikipedia articles on [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) and [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions#POSIX_basic_and_extended) are very useful and informative.

All of the above are defined in POSIX.1-2008, so they are portable across all POSIX-y operating systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these informations. Unfortunately I can not use nftw because it is for a school project and this function is not authorized.

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: In that case, maybe you should consider a loop over all command-line parameters, instead of just using the first one, `av[1]`? That way you could supply multiple glob patterns, for example `'*' '*/*' '*/*/*'`, to look at files up to three directories deep. Recursively scanning directories is very easy to trip up, and really, **truly**, should be done carefully.

Comment: One of my favourite trippers-uppers is running `new="dirname"; i=1; while true; do old="$new"; new="dirname$i"; i=$[i+1]; mv "$old" "$new" ; done` in another window, within the tree you are recursively checking. (It renames a directory originally named `dirname` as `dirname1` with the number increasing every time, as often as it can. It is a stress test of a kind.) A properly written tree recursion does not mind, although it may miss the subtree starting at that changing-name-directory. Badly written implementations will get confused and repeat stuff, or crash.

Comment: Even nastier stress tests are simple to contrive. In particular, renaming within the same directory is a "light" operation on the filesystem, but moving between directories is much more work -- and much more likely to confuse or crash badly written tree scanners. You might think that is overkill or rare, but it really is not! For example, log files are "rotated", and this often includes a triplet of renames (or moves). Same with editing files in emacs/vi/nano/gedit/etc. Or you might move a folder using your Desktop Environment, while your program is working. **Such things do happen.**