# Using POSIX glob() function, gl_pathv is returning NULL — how do I get the file name?

Tags: c, linux, file, glob

I'm trying to get the first file name that ends in `.c`.
I have a `file.c` in my directory, and I expect this to be printed.  However, `(null)` keeps getting printed and I don't understand why.

This is my current code:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    glob_t buf;
    
    buf.gl_offs = 2;
    
    glob("*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &buf);
    
    printf("%ld", buf.gl_pathc);
    printf("%s", buf.gl_pathv[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Not sure its right one but did you have a look at this [list-files-in-directories-using-glob-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641085/list-files-in-directories-using-glob-in-c)

Comment: @IrAM I did. This was my code based off that and the docs. I still was unable to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `buf.gl_offs = 2;`, and you passed `GLOB_DOOFFS` to [`glob()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html), so you told it to leave two unused slots at the beginning of the `gl_argv` list of pointers; it did what you asked, and those slots are NULL pointers.  The idea behind the empty slots is that the code is likely to want to add a command name and maybe some arguments where those slots are, so that `buf.gl_pathv` could be passed to [`execv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html), for example.  The POSIX specification of `glob()` says *"The first pointer after the last pathname shall be a null pointer"* which is required by `execv()`, of course.

Use:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    glob_t buf;

    buf.gl_offs = 2;

    if (glob("*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &buf) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "glob() failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%ld\n", buf.gl_pathc);
    printf("%s\n", buf.gl_pathv[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < buf.gl_pathc + buf.gl_offs + 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu: [%s]\n", i,
               (buf.gl_pathv[i] == NULL ? "<null>" : buf.gl_pathv[i]));
    }

    globfree(&buf);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is lazy; it is relying on `printf("%s\n", buf.gl_pathv[0]);` not to crash when passed a null pointer as a string (original code).  That is not required by the C standard.  The main loop shows what you should do for reliable code — you should map the null pointers before you call `printf()`.

On my machine, it produced:

```
28
(null)
0: [<null>]
1: [<null>]
2: [alarm47.c]
3: [book41.c]
4: [checkeuid.c]
5: [dec37.c]
6: [glob61.c]
7: [grid17.c]
8: [hms37.c]
9: [int89.c]
10: [ll11.c]
11: [log41.c]
12: [pipe17.c]
13: [pipe29.c]
14: [pipe31.c]
15: [pipe43.c]
16: [pipe73.c]
17: [pipe83.c]
18: [prtree37.c]
19: [rc61.c]
20: [rep31.c]
21: [rn83.c]
22: [rn89.c]
23: [sh31.c]
24: [sh47.c]
25: [sh67.c]
26: [sh71.c]
27: [sh79.c]
28: [sh97.c]
29: [test-strsep.c]
30: [<null>]
```

Note that the count in `buf.gl_pathc` does not include the vacant slots specified by `buf.gl_offs` or the terminating null pointer.  I had to check the list of file names in my directory — there are 28 `.c` files, as it happens.  (An earlier version of the code didn't step all the way through the list of names.)

JFTR: I tested on a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.  This must have taken ages to answer.  I ran the code, and it gave a segfault (not sure if that is intentional or not), but at least now I understand  what's going on.  Also, as I understand setting `buf.gl_offs = 0;` is fine also.  As long as I only want the filenames.

Comment: You might get the seg fault from the sloppy `printf()`, but you did say you saw `(null)`.  Have you been able to track down exactly what crashes? Yes, setting `gl_offs` to `0` is fine if you only want the names; you could also omit `GL_DOOFFS` (and pass `0` for the flags argument to `glob()`). As to time — the basic answer didn't take long, but polishing took some time. OTOH, it was useful to me as a learning experience — I need to use `glob()` (or maybe [`wordexp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html)) for a program I need to change to handle globbing.

Comment: Yes, I think I was getting an overflow when I tried to use a `for` loop.  The problem was easy enought to fix.   glob() is really handy, there is no doubt about that :)

Comment: And, just to be definitive: the program above should not crash unless `printf()` crashes on a null pointer for a string.